# Where to get payerId when executing approved payment in PayPal SDK (Java)

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am developing payment checkout function for my iOS app.

The server backend is written in java.

Data that I get after user approved payment in PayPalPaymentViewController with `intent` being `authorize` is

```
{
    client =     {
        environment = sandbox;
        "paypal_sdk_version" = "2.14.2";
        platform = iOS;
        "product_name" = "PayPal iOS SDK";
    };
    response =     {
        "authorization_id" = 6238627648439564E;
        "create_time" = "2016-09-23T08:54:18Z";
        id = "PAY-8J788131PV1025742K7SO3MQ";
        intent = authorize;
        state = approved;
    };
    "response_type" = payment;
}
```

After that, I send `id` (`PAY-8J37....`) for server to execute payment.

Server code here:

```
Payment payment = new Payment();
payment.setId(paymentId);
APIContext apiContext = new APIContext(PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID_SANDBOX, PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET_SANDBOX, "sandbox");
PaymentExecution paymentExecution = new PaymentExecution();
paymentExecution.setPayerId("");//<--- payerId is required
try {
    payment.execute(apiContext, paymentExecution);
} catch (PayPalRESTException e) {
    //print error
}
```

Then `PayPalRESTException` is caught.
The error detail is: `field payer_id must not be blank`

This problem has taken me hours of googling.

Moreover, what does `authorization_id` mean in iOS SDK response? Is it useless?

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of googling, I have figured out the answer.

It was my fault of misunderstanding payment flow.

My mobile payment flow has should be

- [user] authorizes payment, `payment_id` and `authorization_id` are returned. User's account is deposited. Pass `authorization_id` to [server]
- [server] uses `authorization_id` to capture payment. Don't forget to set `is_final_capture` to `true` in the case of one time payment. After capture, merchant account is funded up. [server] increase user's balance.

Thanks for concern